# PHP how to get clean url from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] with no parameters

Tags: php, string, url

is it possible that I can only get the clean url with no parameters.

this is an example.

```
$dis_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $dis_url;
```

returns into:

```
'/mysite.com/subdir?message=value&message2=value2'
```

is it posible that it will return into:

```
'/mysite.com/subdir'
```

the parameter will not be included?

does anyone have an idea about my case? thanks in advance...

Comment: use `parse_url` to split it up and use the parts you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`strtok`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) and [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

```
$dis_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$uri = trim(strtok($dis_url, '?'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dis_url = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
echo $dis_url;
```

It will only shows the PHP File name itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)**

```
    $parts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $required = $parts['path'];
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use  **[parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)** function

```
<?php
  $dis_url ="http://example.com/mobile?u=me";
  $url=parse_url($dis_url);
  $scheme=$url["scheme"];
  $host=$url["host"];
  $path=$url["path"];
  echo $scheme."://".$host.$path;
?>
```

Output: **http://example.com/mobile**

> **Source** :  http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace( $_SERVER['REQUEST_QUERY'], '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```